# Nearest neighbour in SAS

Tags: sas, geospatial, spatial

I have a point data set containing latitude, longitude and elevation data.  I would like to identify the nearest neighbour of a given point by using the distance between any two given points (2d or 3d).  Could anybody suggest the different methods available in SAS for such geo-spatial data analysis and an example SAS code?  Thanks.

Comment: Check geodist function. Relatively new in SAS.

Comment: -@Reese, @user..Thanks.  The geodist function takes latitude and longitude as arguments.  However, I have hundreds of data points in a text file, each point having the lat, long, and elevation information.  I would like to compute distances among a set of neighbors for a given point.  Then I would like to select the nearest neighbors for each of those points based on a given distance value.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You say a set of neighbours? How do you know which ones? You should post some sample data for input/output and anything you've tried to stay in line with SO rules as well.

Comment: Realistically this isn't a very good question because it's essentially looking for a tutorial in the subject; without much more specific data as Reese notes it's not likely to get a good answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to look into the clustering procedures, as KNN style clustering is pretty close to what you want (and at minimum cluster analysis can get you to a 'set' of neighbors to check).  PROC MODECLUS, PROC FASTCLUS, PROC CLUSTER all give you some value here, as does PROC DISTANCE which is used as input in some cases to the above.  Exactly what you want to use depends on what you need and your speed/size constraints (PROC CLUSTER is very slow with large datasets, but gives more useful results oftentimes).

Comment: Thanks Joe, I think this answers my questions.  Here are a couple of useful links that I found which support your comments.  http://www.sas-programming.com/search/label/Nearest%20Neighbor http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Finding_nearest_neighbors

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of nearest-neighbour calculation via the use of SQL (given in the SAS help file somewhere):

```
options ls=80 ps=60 nodate pageno=1 ;
data stores;
  input Store $ x y;
  datalines;
store1 5 1
store2 5 3
store3 3 5
store4 7 5
;
data houses;
   input House $ x y;
   datalines;
house1 1 1
house2 3 3
house3 2 3
house4 7 7
;

options nodate pageno=1 linesize=80 pagesize=60;

proc sql;
   title 'Each House and the Closest Store';
   select house, store label='Closest Store',
          sqrt((abs(s.x-h.x)**2)+(abs(h.y-s.y)**2)) as dist
              label='Distance' format=4.2
      from stores s, houses h

    group by house
      having dist=min(dist);
quit;
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote 2 macros to accomplish this!

**first macro** to take one input gps location and use the lat and lon as a set value new variables for the "neighbor" location dataset. compute all distance and select the min value and store in temp dataset.

**second** calling macro loop through the input datset and to pass in the indivial gps location, call the first macro to do the work and append each min distance to my output dataset.

```
/*** first concatenate your input lat, lon as well as some id into a | seperate long string for later %scan into individual input ***/

%macro min_distance;

data compute_all_dis;
set all_neighbor_gps_locations;
/** here create a new variable to this big dataset with the one point gps value***/
 first_lat = &latitude;
 first_lon = &longitude;
 ID = &PERIOD;
/** compute all **/
 distance = geodist(lat, long, first_lat, first_lon, 'dm');
run;

/** get the shorted distance***/
 proc sql;

 create table closest_neighbor as
 select milepost,OFF_PERIOD_ID, lat, long, first_lat, first_lon, distance 
 from compute_all_dis
    having distance = min ( distance);
quit;


%mend min_distance;



%macro find_all_closest_neighbors;

data _null_;
runno=countw("&ID",'|');
call symputx('runno',put(runno,8.));
run;

%put &runno;

    %do i=1 %to &runno;

    %let PERIOD = %SCAN(&OFF_ID, &i, "|");

    %let latitude = %SCAN (&LAT_I, &i, "|");
    %let longitude = %SCAN (&LONG_I, &i, "|");

    %min_distance;

    proc datasets nowarn;
    append base= pout.all_close_neighbors   data=closest_neighbor;
    run;

%end;
%mend find_all_closest_neighbors;
%find_all_closest_neighbors;
```

Comment: ok, here is the sanitized version of my working code. hope this helps: I tried to paste the code, but the text box says its too many chars, too long. will figure out how to post the code after lunch...